# Running "irb" changes my zsh to bash on iTerm2

Tags: bash, command-line, iterm, zsh

I'm running OSX 10.9.4, and my default shell is set to z shell.

I was just working out my installation of Ruby and RVM and playing around with irb when I suddenly notice that my window title says "bash" instead of my default zsh heading.

Running `echo $SHELL` returned `/bin/bash`, and I confirmed that I was running bash.

The (temporary) fix was simple - run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`, but this instance repeated the switch to bash every time I executed `irb`.

I was not able to replicate the situation, but I was wondering if anyone had insight into this issue so that I don't run into this error again.

Comment: check https://encrypted.google.com/#safe=off&q=interactive+ruby+shell+zsh

Comment: Unfortunately, none of those are my issue. There was a glitch that switched my shell to bash when I ran `irb`, and I have not found any results explaining the cause.

Comment: Have you tried to file a bug against irb?  it might well be possible that irb is the sole cause of this problem you are having